# Tupled function composition

Tags: f#, function-composition

I'm curious why this

```
let f = (fun a b -> a, b) >> obj.Equals
```

gives the error

> No accessible member or object constructor named 'Equals' takes 1 arguments

but this works

```
let f = (fun a -> a, a) >> obj.Equals
```

Comment: The error message I get when I try that is _This expression was expected to have type `a -> 'b * 'a` but here has type `'c * 'd`_, which is a bit more informative. It more clearly corresponds to what kvb wrote in his nice answer. I'm not sure why you're getting a different message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the types.  `(>>)` has type `('a -> 'b) ->('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'c)`, but you're trying to call it with arguments of type `'a -> ('b -> 'a*'b)` and `obj * obj -> bool`, which can't be made to fit together like that.

You could of course define a new combinator for composing binary and unary functions:

```
let ( >>* ) f g a b = f a b |> g
```

in which case you can use it in your example instead of `(>>)`.

Comment: Ah. I overlooked `>>`'s first arg being unary. That strange error message (which I'm still getting) was throwing me off. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Without defining a new combinator operator:

```
let f = (fun a b -> a, b) >> (<<) obj.Equals
```

`>> (<<)` is a nice trick, and can also be extended for more arguments:

```
let compose3 f g = f >> (<<) ((<<) g)
val compose3 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> ('d -> 'e) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'e)
```